# Valgrind on ARM: Simple C++ programs is not pointing the memory errors

Tags: c++, arm, valgrind

I have cross compiled the valgrind using the Yocto arm sdk for my target. I am able to generate the proper stack traces for simple c programs.

But when I execute the c++ programs on valgrind, the valgrind is not showing any useful information. I have copied the c++ libraries with debug symbols to the target. But still I am not able to get any useful information.

If I execute the same program on X86 target, I am able to see the memory errors. Can you please help me find out the issue?

Comment: "the valgrind is not showing any useful information" what is it showing?

Comment: It is showing only address information about memory leak, I am expecting the same output like in desktop environment. I have tried the same binary with debug symbols and I am able to point out where exactly issue occurred

Comment: Maybe there are no memory errors on ARM. Can you post a [mcve]?